# How can I make a line graph showing the times in day start at 1:00AM and ending at 11:00PM in Javascript And Css

Tags: javascript, html, css, graph

I am trouble making a line graph showing the times in day start at 1:00AM and ending at 11:00PM in Javascript And Css Like Stripe
[image]

I'm on a tight deadline so any help would be much appreicated

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get. The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @AustenHolland I am knew to graphs and tried searching this up on the web and couldn't find anything therefore there was nothing I could try

Comment: There are many different already made libraries you can use for charts. A quick google search shows 3 examples. [Charts.js](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/stepped.html), [CanvasJS](https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-line-chart/), and [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)